# How least squares be solved using orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

Consider as shown below where I have my data in vector $y$ and some functions in $A$ and their coefficients $c$ in a vector $x$.

[image]

The problem was to find the function that estimates some data. I have solved this by virtue of $Ax=b$ so to find $b$ I can compute the pseudo inverse and the coefficients are found by  $A^+b=x$ where $A^+$ is the pseudo inverse. Thus I have a matrix $A$ to estimate $y$ with coefficients in $x$.

The above method works.
My question:

How can I do this using a projection matrix? This is my attempt: To make $b$ unto the $range(A)$ it can be projected down using a projection matrix $P$. Thus it can be stated $Pb=Ax$

Then it can be stated $A^+Pb=x$ However this did not work as the dimensions did not check out. So how would this correctly be done? The formula for the projection matrix I used was $P=A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$. Also the book I am following stated there are many ways to find the least-squares solution either by QR, Cholesky, SVD, $Pb=Ax$ and the one I used $A^+b=x$.

Comment: The formula $(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$ **is** the pseudoinverse $A^+$, when $A$ has linearly independent columns (you should check the four defining properties are satisfied). $A^+b$ produces the vector $x$ so that $Ax \in \operatorname{range} A$ is closest to $b$. This makes $AA^+x = A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*x$ the actual nearest point in $\operatorname{range} A$.

Comment: I dont understand why the emphasis on is? So you are telling that $A^+y=x$ gives the closest $x$  to $b$ and when I have found my x with the method $A^+y=x$ then i should do this: $AA^+x=y$  thus to find x it becomes $x=A^+Ab$. And this x becomes the actual nearest point? I tried that and it did not work. What did i misunderstand?

My matrix A is  $2427x6 $ and $A^+$ is $6x1213$. Projection P becomes $2427x1213$ and my data is $1213x1$. How do I get my vector $x$ in $6x1$ using the projection matrix P?  Using your method.

Comment: The emphasis is about highlighting that the two methods are not so different. I'm not sure where $y$ has come from, but I'm saying that $AA^+$ is the projection matrix (in general) onto $\operatorname{range} A$, and, in the case where the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, this matrix becomes $A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$. So, if you want to project $b$ onto $\operatorname{range} A$, you calculate $AA^+b$ (or equivalently, calculate $x = A^+b$, then calculate $Ax$). I don't follow what the vectors or matrices are in your comment, nor do I follow your calculations.

Comment: The projection matrix is $AA^+$ where $A^+ = (A^*A)^{-1}A^*$ so the projection matrix is: $p=A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$. I dont see how it is specific to the linear independent collums case, the way I see it generally it is the way I stated it. What did you mean by it?

I got the rest of your explanation.

Comment: is the problem overconstrained (more rows/data than model variables)?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou  There are 1234 data points and I am trying to find the coefficients for 6 functions.  So yes it is overdetermined/overconstrained I think.

Comment: @Hamzalihi For future reference, you should tag me, just as I have tagged you. Otherwise the system will assume your comment is generically about your post, and not inform me you have replied. As for your question, the linearly independent columns are necessary (and sufficient) for $(A^*A)^{-1}$ to exist. If we don't have linearly independent columns, then $A^+$ still exists, but we can't simply use this formula to find it.